# PHP Soap WS Secured Authorization - I Can't login

Tags: php, soap, service, authorization

I want login Soap API Service URL https://88.255.136.99:83/service.svc/service?wsdl

I use PHP Class https://gist.github.com/tschoffelen/6211278

I select PasswordText return code:

> Check User read error = Invalid username or password
>
> Username and password correct.

I can't login service.

Have c# login

```
ServiceClient web = newServiceClient("WsSecured"); 

    web.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = “kullanıcı adı”;
           web.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = “kullanıcı şifre”;
           web.Open();
    
    System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback =((sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved probem my login data false :)